# How to politely avoid answering questions about a possible new job when resigning?

Tags: communication, colleagues, resignation, manager

I have been in my current position for 7 months.
I want to hand my notice in soon because I do not like the job and the experience has been negative, but I dread answering questions from my colleagues and managers such as 'Why are you leaving?' and 'Do you have a new job?' 'Which job are you going to?'. A previous manager has let me work for them in a different department of the large company I work for which is a lower skillset than what I currently do. Because of this I am not overly eager to tell everyone my new job. How do I politely tell my colleagues that I dont want to share my career plans and new job etc?

Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

Just keep it simple.

> Do you have a new job?

"Yes"

> Why are you leaving?

"Because I think my new job will suit me better."

> Which job are you going to?

"Thanks for asking, but I'd rather not say right now."

Answer (score 5):

A simple "Ah, sorry, but it's a bit personal" will usually clue people in that you're not looking to discuss a topic at length. This answer has the bonus of working in a variety of settings.

Answer (score -4):

Why are you leaving?

> I postulated spontaneously on a job that had interesting required
>   skills that I did not expected to receive an invitation for an
>   interview. Surprisingly, I even got an offer that I cannot refuse.

Where are you going?

> I agreed to not disclose it now because the new employer will officially announce it the moment I will arrive.

Comment: I understand the motivation to deflect and inflate the person's situation, but this seems like dangerous advice given that this person is moving to a different role within their current company (though, I'm not sure I agree with it in other contexts either).

Even if the company is large, it is very likely that social circles overlap and the exaggeration/misdirection will be detected and could be interpreted as a lie. 

Moving to a lower-skilled job is an embarrassing, but an altogether common occurrence, being perceived as having lied about your job move could be damaging.